# Maximise specific infinite product

Tags: products

We consider the infinite product:

$$\frac{1}{c}\prod_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{c^n}{c^n+1} = \frac{1}{c}\frac{c}{c+1}\frac{c^2}{c^2+1}\frac{c^3}{c^3+1} \cdots$$

For which real value of $c > 1$ has the product its maixmum?

Background of Question: Expected number of equilibria in multi-person games on trees of uniform width c, c=3 gives maximum fraction of equilibria for integral c. Allowing real-valued c may give more insight.

Ingo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimal $c$ is the unique positive root of $\sum k/(1+c^k)=1$, numerically about 2.43. I doubt that it is expressable via known constants and elementary functions.

Comment: Hi Fedor, thx. I want to put you in the acknowledgement of a paper where I mention your finding. Feel free to let me know your true name by email to ingo.althoefer@uni-jena.de   Thx again.

Comment: Hi Ingo, my real name is very much the same: Fedor Petrov.